# python; program won't write to output file inside a main function

Tags: python

```
# Modularity and Records Assignment
# rubiks cube collection

print("taha_mods.py\n")

print("Rubiks cube storage & collections.")
print("Enter cube information, search, modify")

def record_vars(): # function for rubiks cube information collection (for records!!!!)
    cube_info = [0,0,0]
    cube_info[0] = input("Enter the manufacturer provided name of your rubiks cube: ")
    cube_info[1]= input("Enter whether or not your cube is stickerless or stickered: ")
    cube_info[2] = input("Enter whether or not your cube is magnetic or not: ")
    return cube_info

def action(): # user action. user puts "enter, search, modify"
        user_action = input("Action: ")
        #user_options = ['enter' and 'Enter' and 'Search' and 'search' and 'modify' and 'Modify'] # list 4user actions (below 79 words)
        while (user_action != "enter" and user_action != "Enter" and user_action != "search" and user_action != "Search" and user_action != "modify" and user_action != "Modify" ):
            print("Invalid Input")
            user_action = input("Action: ")
            
        return user_action #returns Action: prompt it to be used zd!


def main():
    
    file_out = 'cube.txt'
    
    output_file = open(file_out, "w")
    if (action() == "enter" or "Enter"):
        print("Enter the manufacturer name, sticker variation, and the magnetic status of your cube.")
        print(record_vars())
    output_file.write('test')
    output_file.close()



main() #main section runs da code
```

I have a school assignment. I'm trying to write the information from the function def record_vars() into the output file "cube.txt".
I tested it with writing a simple phrase to the output file, but the phrase itself doesn't show up in the output life like it's supposed to.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `if (action() == "enter" or "Enter"):` is not the correct way to test for two values. It should be `if (action().lower() == "enter"):`

Comment: The phrase should definitely show up in the file. Are you sure you're looking for the file in the correct directory?

Comment: Try adding `./` to the file path if it is in the same directory. it should look like this: `./cube.txt`

Comment: @2pichar Leaving out the directory means to put it in `.`

Comment: @Barmar i've double checked. i've made sure my .txt file is saved in the same folder my .py file is saved. i'm on linux ubuntu if that changes anything

Comment: I tested code on Linux Mint 20.3 (based on Ubuntu 20.04) and it writes `text` in file - so it works. Maybe first delete `'cube.txt'` to check if it will create it again. You could also display `Current Working Directory` - `print( os.getcwd() )` to see in which folder it runs code. If it runs code in different folder then it also write it in diferrent folder than you expect.

Comment: It won't be saved in the same directory as the script, it will be in your current working directory.

Comment: @Barmar  got it thanks for the help. Turns out I was saving it at the wrong location, and I had to do that os.cwd thing to find the right location. appreciate it!